# Do I connect grounds on a 4-pin MOSFET with kelvin source?

Tags: mosfet, ground, mosfet-driver

I have a 4-pin MOSFET with two source pins. One is for the driver source (the so called kelvin source) and one is for the power source (the normal one you'd find on any MOSFET).

I've got a driver to control the gate signal from a microcontroller.

I've found this image online that is similar to my setup:
[image: Image comparing a 3-pin MOSFET with a 4-pin MOSFET]
([source](https://efficiencywins.nexperia.com/efficient-products/LFPAK88-takes-a-shorter-path-to-efficiency.html))

In the 3-pin MOSFET image, the grounds of the source and the driver are shared. This is what I'm used to doing.
However, in the 4-pin MOSFET image, the two sources are connected to different grounds.

So there are two options afaik:

1. Keep the grounds separate (I can in my design)
2. Route the driver source trace straight to the driver ground pin (keeping it separate from the ground plane), which would only then make proper connection with ground

Which one would you recommend?

My concerns:

- For 1, what happens when I end up powering my driver and microntroller with an LDO that gets its power from the bigger MOSFET power source? That would introduce a common ground again, but it'd be 'far away' though. Would this be bad? Is there anything I can do to mitigate the bad effects?
- For 2, while I think this would stop the inductance problem (which is what the kelvin source is for), I think it's possible that too large a current will go to ground via that route which would burn out the MOSFET. Would it? Can this be mitigated?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're going to use a "Kelvin" sense circuit, the signal ground has to be decoupled from the power ground. That's the whole point. If you can't decouple the sense detection from the power circuity, it's not a "Kelvin" connection.

You've suggested that you may get large ground currents through your "sense" circuit. That's not a "Kelvin" circuit. Either you can decouple the circuits -- in which case a Kelvin sense circuit is a good idea -- or you can't -- in which case it's not a Kelvin circuit no matter how many wires and terminals you have.

Answer (score 2):

`To control the gate signal from a microcontroller` is too broad a description of your intended application. As an example of more focused application, in boost converters MOSFETs with a driver source terminal are used to improve switching loss. Maybe catches and solutions used to improve switching loss in boost converters using MOSFET packages with driver source terminals are relevant (with necessary circuit changes) for your application.

A behavior you describe in `My concerns`, item 2 (`that too large a current will go to ground via that route which would burn out the MOSFET`) is similar to potentially dangerous voltage surges generated in a bridge configuration. The surge generation problem is addressed in ROHM Semiconductor's Application Note No. 62AN010E Rev.002 [Gate-Source Voltage Surge Suppression Methods](https://fscdn.rohm.com/en/products/databook/applinote/discrete/sic/mosfet/sicmosfet-surge%20suppression_an-e.pdf) (page 2/7, section **Surge Suppression Circuit**):

> ...However, the major concern is on the non-switching side (Figure 2 Event (II)). This is because, since the switching side is already turned on, if the positive surge voltage on the non-switching side exceeds the gate threshold voltage (VGS(th)) of the MOSFET, self-turn-on occurs and a through current flows. ...

And although the same document tries to alleviate this concern

> However, because the trans-conductance of a SiC MOSFET is smaller than that of a Si-based MOSFET, excessive through current does not flow immediately. Therefore, even if a through current flows, there is basically no problem if the cooling capacity is sufficient and the Tj(max) of the MOSFET is not exceeded.

It still recommends to provide a surge suppression circuit:

> However, since it affects the overall system efficiency and is not in a favourable state, it is necessary to add a surge suppression circuit to avoid the voltage exceeding the VGS(th) of the MOSFET.

An example of the surge suppression circuit is shown in Figure 4 of ROHM Semiconductor's Application Note No. 62AN010E Rev.002 [Gate-Source Voltage Surge Suppression Methods](https://fscdn.rohm.com/en/products/databook/applinote/discrete/sic/mosfet/sicmosfet-surge%20suppression_an-e.pdf) (page 2/7, section **Surge Suppression Circuit**).

[image: Surge Suppression Circuit, AN No. 62AN010E Rev.002, Fig 4]

**RECOMMENDATION**: Provide a source suppression circuit for a driver-source MOSFET used in your design.